# Saved search Netsuite error in Summary Criteria

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

Im making a saved search ( find  fully applied  customer payments)  with a summary in criteria
[image]

In UI  it works fine, but in suitescript  gives me this error:

> ERROR CODE: INVALID_SRCH_SUMMARY_TYP \n DESCRIPTION: An
> nlobjSearchFilter contains an invalid summary type: formulanumeric:
> SUM.

I have tried to load the search

```
var  searchPayment=search.load({
                   id:'customsearch_paymentsCXC'
                });
```

Or using the SearchExport extension:

```
search.create({
                    type: "customerpayment",
                    filters:
                    [
                        ["type","anyof","CustPymt"], 
                        "AND", 
                        ["systemnotes.field","anyof","CUSTBODY_REFJOURNALENTRY_IVA"], 
                        "AND", 
                        ["systemnotes.date","within","thisweek"], 
                        "AND", 
                        ["customer.custentity_zona_cliente","anyof",zonaid], 
                        "AND", 
                        ['sum(formulanumeric: CASE WHEN SUM(NVL({appliedtolinkamount},0)) = MAX(NVL({amount},0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)','equalto','1']
                     ],
                     columns:
                     [
                        search.createColumn({name: "tranid", label: "Document Number"}),
                        search.createColumn({name: "custbody_fe_uuid_cfdi_33", label: "UUID CFDI v3.3"}),
                        search.createColumn({name: "custbody_fe_sf_mensaje_respuesta", label: "Mensaje de Respuesta"}),
                        search.createColumn({
                           name: "tranid",
                           join: "appliedToTransaction",
                           label: "Document Number"
                        }),
                        search.createColumn({
                           name: "internalid",
                           join: "appliedToTransaction",
                           label: "Internal ID"
                        })
                    ]
                 });
```

and I still getting the same error in the filter with summary :

```
['sum(formulanumeric: CASE WHEN SUM(NVL({appliedtolinkamount},0)) = MAX(NVL({amount},0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)','equalto','1']
```

what Im missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
...
Filters: [
    ...
    'AND',
    ['formulanumeric: CASE WHEN sum(nvl({appliedtolinkamount},0)) = max(nvl({amount},0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END','is','1']
],
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a filter object instead of string array

```
...
Filters: [
    ...
    'AND',
    Search.createFilter({
        name: 'formulanumeric',
        summary: 'sum',
        operator: 'equalto',
        values: 1,
        formula: 'CASE WHEN SUM(NVL({appliedtolinkamount},0)) = MAX(NVL({amount},0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END'
    })
],
...
```

Comment: this works too but  i have to change the operator to 'is'